# Issues Getting ScrollSpy to Work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on getting a basic scroll nav working using bootstrap's ScrollSpy plug-in.
I have my data-spy and data-target setup in my body, but the active link styling isn't being applied as I scroll.

Here is a link to my current code (boostrap css and js files are linked here) 
http://codepen.io/drustin/pen/QdmKdN

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- This is the scrollable area -->
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
  <!-- The navbar where the anchors <a> are used ot jump to a section in the scrollable container -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
       <!-- These are the links placed in the nav across the top -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div>
  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>This is some text....try out the nav bar scroll, hopefully it works</p>
    <p>This is some text....try out the nav bar scroll, hopefully it works</p>
  </div>

  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>This is some text....try out the nav bar scroll, hopefully it works</p>
    <p>This is some text....try out the nav bar scroll, hopefully it works</p>
  </div>

  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>This is some text....try out the nav bar scroll, hopefully it works</p>
    <p>This is some text....try out the nav bar scroll, hopefully it works</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your CodePen link works!

Answer (score 0):

The Codepen doesn't include jQuery. Just make sure jQuery is included before Bootstrap JS and it works...

`<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">`

http://www.codeply.com/go/OEEgFpFnaN

Comment: Thanks! Weirdly enough I can get it working everywhere but code pen after these changes... I'll tinker around and see why.

Comment: Needed to have jQuery before the Bootstrap js link for it to work in code pen.